# Read a online cvs file generated by a script

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to read a cvs file generated by some kind of script (I guess) and write the data on to two different worksheets labled "LT" and "ST", i.e. Long term and Short term. The Workbooks.open function is not working here, I think because the url doen't points to the cvs file directly.

I found this url by clicking on a download link on "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm". The the download manager shows "https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true" as the download link.

Please note that I do not want to save the online cvs file. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
Sub Get_NSE_ASM_Data()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim NSE_ASM_File As Workbook
    
    Set NSE_ASM_File = Workbooks.Open("https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true", 0, True, 2)
    
    Dim Row_Counter As Integer
    Dim Serial_Number As Integer
    Dim Worksheet_Name As String
            
    Do While True
        Row_Counter = 1
        
        MsgBox NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value
        
        If IsEmpty(NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value) Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value = "Long Term" Then
            Worksheet_Name = "LT"
            Serial_Number = 1
        ElseIf NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value = "Short Term" Then
            Worksheet_Name = "ST"
            Serial_Number = 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value) Then
            Worksheets(Worksheet_Name).Range("A" & Serial_Number).Value = NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Row_Counter).Value
            Worksheets(Worksheet_Name).Range("B" & Serial_Number).Value = NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Row_Counter).Value
            Worksheets(Worksheet_Name).Range("C" & Serial_Number).Value = NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & Row_Counter).Value
            Worksheets(Worksheet_Name).Range("D" & Serial_Number).Value = NSE_ASM_File.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & Row_Counter).Value
            
            Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
            Serial_Number = Serial_Number + 1
        End If
    Loop
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Get_NSE_ASM_Data
End Sub
```

I think the webpage "nseindia.com/reports/asm" also submits other values, maybe like session id or maybe a cookie for authentication of some kind, along with the download request to the link "nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true". Is there a way I can find all the values which are required for successfully downloading the cvs file?

Following is some data found using Mozilla Firefox Web Developer Tool. Maybe this helps in understanding the problem.

```
GET
    scheme: https
    host: www.nseindia.com
    filename: /api/reportASM
    csv: true
    Address: xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
    Status: 200 OK
    Version: HTTP/2
    Transferred: 8.57 KB (22.20 KB size)
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin


Response Headers (638B)
    HTTP/2 200 OK
    content-type: text/csv
    x-dns-prefetch-control: off
    x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
    x-download-options: noopen
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    access-control-allow-origin: "nseindia.com"
    access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST
    access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
    content-disposition: attachment; filename=asm-latest.csv
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 8139
    date: Sun, 24 Oct 2021 05:38:15 GMT
    vary: Accept-Encoding
    server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
    server-timing: edge; dur=42
    server-timing: origin; dur=521
    X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
        

Request Headers (1.637 KB)
    GET /api/reportASM?csv=true HTTP/2
    Host: www.nseindia.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Connection: keep-alive
    Referer: https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm
    
    Cookie: nsit=WDLyySd-BEf4jobqRLnN38zJ; AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=1A58BA1A2177719F599841268304FA8B~000000000000000000000000000000~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; bm_sv=B9AFDF71BBEEFE26BF7DF7CF92805198~DS6ZL6s5VisVFhZzPuxnt5756VRKTjesDG7RJYFSXdPJ7T3tVDrYIuA68346qpwSp0MGv28qblcmmxxjmduD1gKGQr1j3ocC+SsMIIBJLuVrea5dlDZvUxL5FVm91iuiCI/WKQiLluK7Lditw8mJzhMa7yCgnmVWcqsnAWAwW+U=; _ga=GA1.2.995064782.1635052492; _gid=GA1.2.1236022296.1635052492; RT="z=1&dm=nseindia.com&si=4e57fd00-5b5a-4bad-ac98-3f4572f59d34&ss=kv4s1c0r&sl=2&tt=n53g&bcn=%2F%2F684d0d3e.akstat.io%2F&nu=ed8553192c8d124be55949cc1b2e99dc&cl=u2j6"; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTYzNTA1MzYxMiwiZXhwIjoxNjM1MDU3MjEyfQ.xfkuwyBsFsmJy6M3NnvAWmxgVzDNPvgJPqUJ6GO4Ucg

    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
```

Problem solved thanks to @ceci. Here is the final code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim winHttpReq As Object
    Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    winHttpReq.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm", False
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm"
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    
    winHttpReq.Send
    'Debug.Print winHttpReq.getAllResponseHeaders
    
    strCookie = winHttpReq.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
    
    
    winHttpReq.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true", False
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm"
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"
    'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "cookie", strCookie
    
    winHttpReq.Send
    'Debug.Print winHttpReq.ResponseText

    Dim arrNSEASMRecords As Variant
    Dim arrNSEASMRecordValues As Variant
    
    arrNSEASMRecords = Split(winHttpReq.ResponseText, vbLf)
    
    Dim intNSEASMRecordsCounter As Integer
    Dim intSerialNumberCounter As Integer
    Dim strWorkSheetName As String
    
    For intNSEASMRecordsCounter = 0 To UBound(arrNSEASMRecords) Step 1
        arrNSEASMRecordValues = Split(arrNSEASMRecords(intNSEASMRecordsCounter), ",")
        
        If arrNSEASMRecordValues(0) = """Long Term""" Then
            strWorkSheetName = "LT"
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents
            intSerialNumberCounter = 1
        ElseIf arrNSEASMRecordValues(0) = """Short Term""" Then
            strWorkSheetName = "ST"
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents
            intSerialNumberCounter = 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(arrNSEASMRecordValues(0)) Then
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("A" & intSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(0), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("B" & intSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(1), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("C" & intSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(2), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("D" & intSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(3), """", "")
            Worksheets(strWorkSheetName).Range("E" & intSerialNumberCounter).Value = Replace(arrNSEASMRecordValues(4), """", "")
            
            intSerialNumberCounter = intSerialNumberCounter + 1
        End If
        
    Next intNSEASMRecordsCounter
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "Resource not found" when pasting https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, after I had posted this question :) . I think the webpage "https://www.nseindia.com/reports/asm" also submits other values, maybe like session id, along with the download request to the link "https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportASM?csv=true". Is there a way I can find all the values which are required for successfully downloading the cvs file?

Comment: you can check this with dev tools in chrome (network > click on the link > you'll see details about what happens). The site will check if you have a valid cookie so you'll first have to grab a cookie before sending your GET call. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+get+cookie

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have few more doubts. Suppose I grab the cookie and set it again before calling the Workbooks.Open function, will it work? Or do I have to create a GET request? If I use the GET request then will I be able to read the csv file without save it, i.e. directly through the stream?

Comment: No you'll have to open the document. Get the content in an array. Close the document. But you can hide this from the user.

Comment: @ceci Thanks a lot, you pointed me in the right direction with the idea of garbing the cookie and setting it again in my next GET request. This solved my problem.