# Excel data parsing says error expecting '{' or '['

Tags: json, excel, vba

Here is my Code i have tried many searching but didnt find right solution please help there.

```
Sub JnewCOP22()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim json As Object, r, r1 As String, i, j As Integer
URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=DRREDDY&section=trade_info"
With req
.Open "GET", URL, False
.send
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
r = json("securityWiseDP")("quantityTraded")
End With
MsgBox r
End Sub
```

The API Data
{"noBlockDeals":true,"bulkBlockDeals":[{"name":"Session I"},{"name":"Session II"}],"marketDeptOrderBook":{"totalBuyQuantity":0,"totalSellQuantity":264,"bid":[{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0}],"ask":[{"price":4659.2,"quantity":264},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0},{"price":0,"quantity":0}],"tradeInfo":{"totalTradedVolume":1945164,"totalTradedValue":92498.58,"totalMarketCap":7713541.51,"ffmc":5659504.6195251,"impactCost":0.02},"valueAtRisk":{"securityVar":10.89,"indexVar":0,"varMargin":10.89,"extremeLossMargin":3.5,"adhocMargin":0,"applicableMargin":14.39}},"securityWiseDP":{"quantityTraded":1945164,"deliveryQuantity":417789,"deliveryToTradedQuantity":21.48,"seriesRemarks":null,"secWiseDelPosDate":"29-OCT-2021 EOD"}}

The error massage says error parsing json <!Doctype h ^ expecting ' {' or '[ '

Comment: Is this the actual json that is coming from the code, or is this json that you obtained as an example?  Check the actual value that appears in your code for .responseText

Comment: You probably need to get a cookie first see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689213/read-a-online-cvs-file-generated-by-a-script)

Comment: Please tell me what to change in coding.

Comment: This is actual json from where i want to bring values. @ChrisStrickland

Comment: I mean, I get valid JSON from that URL, but when I parse it, it returns a value.  See this image: https://i.imgur.com/1g8MGeI.png  I just got 421170.  That's why I think there is some issue.  It would be very unlikely for you to be passing valid JSON to JsonConverter and for it to be responding with that error.  So the first step is to Debug.Print .responseText and see what it actually says, because I don't see how it can be valid JSON and you get that result.  Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: Add a request header `.setRequestHeader "cookie", "nseQuoteSymbols=[{""symbol"":""DRREDDY"",""identifier"":null,""type"":""equity""}];"` and you should get the JSON response (although it shows no data when I tried it).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your request does not return JSON as you expected, but rather an ordinary HTML document.

In order to request a JSON document, you (probably) should set the HTTP request header `Accept` to `application/json`.

Comment: Yes, this is almost certainly correct.  He included valid JSON in the question, but I would bet that this is not the actual value of .responseText

Comment: Where in the coding i have change please tell.